# How to add or push a new row with custom text like "loading more" inside Angular mat-table?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

How to add or push a new row with custom text like  "loading more" inside Angular mat-table ?
Tried to using this.dataSource.data.push('load more') but getting undefined data row.

Comment: Google how to do an "expandable rows" in using mat table. It will be exaclty the same thing. Long story short, you have to use 2 different row templates, 1 that renders data row and 1 that renderes single cell with 'loading' message.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried using expandable rows, but it's getting appended for all the rows. I just wanted to add a temporary row with the text at the end of the current loaded rows and once the new set of rows are added using API data, I want to hide or remove it.

Comment: You just did it wrong.